# call drop after upgrading moto g 1st gen to lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

After upgrading my phone moto g 1st gen to lollipop (5.0.2) update then, when some one is calling then its only one beep nothing else and it's showing as a missed call.

How to fix it?Please help